# Plot with statistical significance annotations in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to make the following plot with `pgfplots`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Are you sure you want no ticks on the y-axis that show the dimension? And did you at least start to draw something with `pgfplots` or do you want somebody to do it from scratch for you?

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome! I have started to draw with pgfplots. In this case, I am mainly interested in drawing the pairwise lines.